# How do I call global functions on Python objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I've seen this page: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html but there doesn't seem to be any way to call functions like `long_lshift` or `long_or`.

It's not essential to me to call these functions, I could also live with the more generic versions, although I'd prefer to call these.  Anyways, is there any way to use these?  What do I need to include?  Below is some example code, where I'd like to use them (simplified):

```
size_t parse_varint(parse_state* state) {
    int64_t value[2] = { 0, 0 };
    size_t parsed = parse_varint_impl(state, value);
    PyObject* low = PyLong_FromLong(value[0]);
    PyObject* high;

    if (value[1] > 0) {
         high = PyLong_FromLong(value[1]);
         PyObject* shift = PyLong_FromLong(64L);
         PyObject* high_shifted = long_lshift(high, shift);
         state->out = long_or(low, high_shifted);
    } else {
        state->out = low;
    }
    PyObject_Print(state->out, stdout, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what happens with the aboev code? Does it compile? Do you get an error message or any warnings? At compile time or run time?

Comment: @JohanL it doesn't compile because I don't know how to include the proper header.  I mean, I could just dig this header up from Python sources and include it, but I want this to compile on any machine where Python development package is installed, not just my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find these functions in documentation, but they appear to be exported in `Python.h` header:

- `PyNumber_Lshift` is the replacement for `long_shift` in my code.
- Similarly, `PyNumber_Or` is the replacement for `long_or` in my code.